# Creating Bitmask for keyboard modifiers + ASCII Code

Tags: character-encoding, compression, bit, bit-shift

I would like to encode three keyboard modifiers (CTRL, ALT, SHIFT) + the ASCII code of the pressed key into a single value. This falls naturally into the category of bitmasks.
One way I could do this is that the sender encodes each key as the following:

```
CTRL: 1000
ALT: 10000
SHIFT: 100000
KeyCode: 1-255
```

For example, if I were to click all modifiers + the last key in the ascii table, I would get:
100000 + 10000 + 1000 + 255 = 111255. The receiver side it would then be possible to do substraction and check if the number goes below 0 as such:

```
has_shift = X - 100000 < 0
has_alt = X - 10000 < 0
has_ctrl = X - 1000 < 0
if has_shift
   X -= 100000
if has_alt
   X -= 10000
if has_ctrl
   X -= 1000
keyCode = X (the remainder)
```

Surely enough, I find this horrible and would assume that this could be done in a far better using bit-shift or something in that ballpark. How could this possibly be done better?

Answer (score 1):

Instead add 256, 512, and 1024 respectively for ctrl, alt, shift. Then use the *and* operator in whatever language you're using (missing from question tags) to extract the modifiers and code. In C and many languages, that operator is `&`. So `X & 1024` is not zero if shift was pressed. `X & 255` is the character code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried bit-shifting originally with CTRL=1 ALT=2 SHIFT=3 respectively, but I assume that my error here was that I should reserve the first 255 to the keycode. Suppose I had some other keyCode scheme ranging to 750. Would it then be correct to start the modifiers at 1024?

Comment: Yes. 1024, 2048, 4096. Those are all just a single one bit in the binary representation of the integer.

Comment: Just a little follow up to this:
Would it also be possible to encode multiple letters in a single mask? I understand the concept when having a set number that represents the "action/modifier" but would  it be possible do define 4 arbitrary letters in a  32bit mask? Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but two bits will encode four symbols.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to encode the string ABC. I assume to encode the correct way would be:
encoded = ord('A') >> 16 | ord('B') >> 8 | ord('C')
decoded = ??

How would I proceed to get back my string ABC?

Comment: Comments are not for this. If you have a new question, you should post it as such.